# How to know the download link of a windows phone 8 application

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, share

I'm developing windows phone 8 application. In which I have to share the application's download link on Facebook and Twitter.

Before publishing the application on to the windows phone store, How could I know the download link of the application.

Because we have to implement the share functionality before publishing the application.

I'm looking forward for your responses.

Thanks & Regards,
Suresh

Answer (score 0):

Basically your application download link format is as follow :

```
http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=<ApplicationId>
```

with `<ApplicationId>` is value of `ProductID` attribute of `App` element in `WMAppManifest.xml` file. That `ProductID` in `WMAppManifest.xml` will be overridden when you submit the Apps to Marketplace, so avoid hardcoding it. [This post](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Generating-a-Windows-Phone-9d19f939#content) demonstrates how to get `<ApplicationId>` from manifest file as well as how to share it using `Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.ShareLinkTask`.

**UPDATE :**

To summarize, create a helper class to read `ApplicationID` from `WMAppManifest.xml` file :

```
public class DeepLinkHelper 
{ 
    private const string AppManifestName = "WMAppManifest.xml"; 
    private const string AppNodeName = "App"; 
    private const string AppProductIDAttributeName = "ProductID"; 

    public static string BuildApplicationDeepLink() 
    { 
        var applicationId = Guid.Parse(GetManifestAttributeValue(AppProductIDAttributeName)); 

        return BuildApplicationDeepLink(applicationId.ToString()); 
    } 

    public static string BuildApplicationDeepLink(string applicationId) 
    { 
        return @"http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=" + applicationId; 
    } 

    public static string GetManifestAttributeValue(string attributeName) 
    { 
        var xmlReaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings 
        { 
            XmlResolver = new XmlXapResolver() 
        }; 

        using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(AppManifestName, xmlReaderSettings)) 
        { 
            xmlReader.ReadToDescendant(AppNodeName); 

            if (!xmlReader.IsStartElement()) 
            { 
                throw new FormatException(AppManifestName + " is missing " + AppNodeName); 
            } 

            return xmlReader.GetAttribute(attributeName); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Then you can get/share download link this way :

```
new Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.ShareLinkTask() 
{ 
    Title = "My Application Deep Link", 
    Message = "My Application Deep Link", 
    LinkUri = new Uri(DeepLinkHelper.BuildApplicationDeepLink()) 
}.Show();
```

Credit to [Pedro Lamas](http://www.pedrolamas.com/) for all above codes.

Comment: why you ignore this and posted [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21258988/2998271) with same content? Same SO question with similar answer to this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13640399/2998271)