# How to get the windows phone application download link from windows store

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, share

I'm developing windows phone 8 application, in which i have the share application functionality.

The main purpose of this share feature is to share the application download link(windows store) on the face-book or twitter.

Before publishing the application to the store, we can't get the download link of the application. But we need this application download link to implement the share feature.

So how can we get/estimate the application download link.

Thanks

Comment: how could you get the download link before publishing the app?

Comment: create API and retrieve link from it

Comment: Could you please tell me how do we create API, I'm new to windows phone 8.

Comment: And also before publishing the app we have to implement the share functionality and we need download link of the application. So how we'll change the code after publishing the application

Answer (score 0):

Quick and easy solution, submit the app to the market without this functionality but not publish it to the marketplace. Then get the deeplink information, put it on the app and then release the update. This will mean double the certification time though.

Or, have the app query a webserver for the information on first start and save the resulting deeplink in the app settings. That way you can publish the app, get the deeplink and then update the information on the webserver side before it's published to the store.